# Is there a way to get rid of blurry preview of Browser review extension in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, blurry

I am new to web development. I'm using VSCode and recently installed an extension called Browser Preview to preview the live webpage. Everything is working fine except this blurry area in the browser.

Extension Link : [Browser Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview)

[Image of Blurred portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPw4V.png)

Besides, Is there any other similar option to view browser in side pan of vs code without opening chrome. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live HTML Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer) is my best option for HTML and CSS only development, This extension allows you to preview your html files in VS Code itself. Use it to quickly set the html and css right for your webpages.

Cons : can't work on PHP and JS.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation Asmoun. I'll be checking that.